# Multiple PFObjects In Parse Query and PFTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Having issues with displaying multiple updated labels with a custom PFTableViewCell and PFQueryTableViewController. The first textKey or object declared does show in after running, but other labels are showing as blank. You will also note as of right now, the date is not pulling either, but I'm working through one problem at a time. I think I need to declare another textKey class but have tried adding to the PFQueryTableViewController.h and initiating but thats not working. Here's my TableViewController:

```
import UIKit; import Parse

class UserRecordsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Event"
        self.textKey = "category"
        self.textKey = "duration"

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "event")
        query.orderByAscending("category")


        return query
    }

    //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {


        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UserRecordsTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UserRecordsTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell


        cell.durationEventLabel.text = object["duration"] as? String
        cell.dateEventLabel.text = object["category"] as? String




        // Date for cell subtitle
        /*var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateForText = object["createdAt"] as NSDate
        cell.dateEventLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateForText)*/







        return cell
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        /*var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as YourDetailViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        }*/
    }




}
```

Here is the custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class UserRecordsTableViewCell: PFTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateEventLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var catEventLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var durationEventLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Here is a selection from my PFQueryTableViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textKey;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided the best approach to my desired look is to go with PFTableViewCell provided by parse framework and simply only show two items. Main category and date as **subtitle**. This is opposed to creating a custom cell which works well with text and image label but not well with two text keys. 
Followed this tutorial and was great:

https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581